# Sending large json data in response body apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices

I have exposed a web service which returns multiple fields from a custom object in json format. It works fine for 3500 records, but increasing records to more than that throws apex heap size exceeded error.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have exposed a webservice i would assume you its an inbound api call to salesforce which means you get 12 MB heap size(async limits).

The best way to deal with this and to have a scalable solution would be to chunk the request in middleware(most preferable) and if you don't have one you have to ask the external system to do it. The high level steps would be

1. External system calls salesforce through middleware
2. Middleware calls salesforce api
3. Salesforce sends 3000 records(breaking point is 3500 approx.) and another parameter that there are more records and the recordids it needs to query
4. Middleware queries salesforce again and this process continues till all records are processed and finally middleware assembles all the record chunks and sends it to external system

**Alternate Solution:**

1. Middleware call salesforce and it returns an API with number of chunks and record ids it needs to query in every chunk
2. Middleware makes parallel call to salesforce for all chunks , gets all the data and then sends one request to external system.

If you dont have a middleware this work needs to be done by the external system.